# fpdf python cells disappearing

Tags: python, fpdf

I created [this program](https://github.com/MysteryCrystal/flashcard-maker) in github that converts quizlet flashcards into large printable ones because quizlet has removed that feature. The one on github works however it doesn't work with larger bits of text. I have changed it to make the font smaller when it doesnt fully fit. However the cell would just disappear. I thought the font was just zero but that's not the case. Even when trying the way below, cells just vanish. [As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veBoS.png)

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import os, math, re, numpy

def group_words(s, n):
    words = s.split()
    for i in range(0, len(words), n):
        yield ' '.join(words[i:i+n])

def printcell(text):
    #105 is the width of 1 cell
    width = pdf.get_string_width(text)
    pdf.set_font("Japanese", size = fontsize)

    if(width >= 104):
        pdf.set_font("Japanese", size = fontsize-5)
        print("splitting")
        words = numpy.array(list(group_words(text,3)))
        print(words)
        words.join('\n')  
        print(words)
        pdf.cell(105, 74.25, words, 1, 1, 'C')
    else:
        pdf.cell(105, 74.25, text, 0, 1, 'C')
```

here is the earlier version that changes font size(i am aware there is no check to make sure the font is not 0):

```
def printcell(text):
    while(pdf.get_string_width(text)>105):
        if (counter == fontsize):
            pass
        else:
            pdf.set_font("Japanese", size = fontsize-counter)
            counter+=1
    pdf.cell(105, 74.25, text, 0, 1, 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pdf.cell(105, 74.25, str(words), 1, 1, 'C')
```

and you might find that you want

```
words = '\n'.join(list(words))
```

Comment: This did help. I also changed cell to multi_cell as per the [docs](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/multi_cell/index.html) but any text that should be going down a line is just layed on top of the previous one.